# API design: naming "I want one more value outside time boundaries"

Tags: api-design

I'm designing an API to query the history of a value over a time period. Think about a temperature value, and you want to query all the values for today.

I have a `from` and a `to` parameter to specify the boundaries of the query. 
The values available may not exactly match the boundaries requested. For example, if from is `2016-02-17T00:00:00Z`, the first value may be on `2016-02-17T00:04:30Z`. To fully represent a graph of the period, it is necessary to retrieve one more value outside the given range. The value on `2016-02-16T23:59:30Z` is useful and it would be convenient for the user to not have to make another query to retrieve it.

So as the API designer I'm thinking about a parameter with a pair a of boolean values that would tell for each boundary: *give me one more value if there is no value exactly on the boundary*.

My question is how to name this parameter as English is not my native language.
Here are a few ideas I have so far but with which I'm not totally satisfied:

- `overflow=true,true`
- `overstep=true,true`
- `edges=true,true`

I would also appreciate any links to existing APIs with that feature, either web API or in programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to make this more of a function/RPC that a traditional rest resource endpoint, so rather than requesting data for a resource between 2 dates like

/myResource?from=x&to=x

something more like

/getGraphData?graphFrom=&graphTo=x

Whilst its only a naming thing, it makes it a bit more acceptable to retrieve results for a task wrapped with outer data, rather than violating parameters potentially giving unexpected or confusing results.